# how to establish connections between a servlet and a socket

Tags: java, servlets, websocket

Supposing I have a servlet that reads and writes a file to a socket and I want to establish a connection between the servlet and the socket, how could this be done?

Well, for a socket, i read somewhere that one just has to do this:

```
URL url  = new URL("http://example.com/getFile");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
```

How could I do the same for a servlet?

I wanted to do this since I will be sending and receiving files between the servlet and the scoket. Also, how would both of them know when the other has sent a file and should read it?

I have searched for this but can't find any site that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what do you mean by 'Socket'. If the socket is a standard protocol (http/https/ftp) then you can use the above piece of code in the Servlet just as you would use in a stand alone program.
If your socket does NOT prescribe to any standard then you might want to open a direct connection using the below piece of code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(server,port);
//Get an input stream from the socket
BufferedReader inputStream = 
     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                     socket.getInputStream()));

//Get  an output stream to the socket.  Note
// that this stream will autoflush.
PrintWriter outputStream = 
     new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
               socket.getOutputStream()),true);
outputStream.println("send_ data");
      System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());
      socket.close();
```

Regarding the file sending piece of code, if the primary task involved is file transfer you can use FTP protocol to send files between the servlet and socket.
you can have a file watcher on the socket end to know when a file is transferred. Refer [filewatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) and [ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200106/urlconnection-ftp-list-files) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your reply. What I want to do is get a file from the socket and then modify it by sending it to the browser as a form. The browser fills in the form and sends back to the servlet which then sends the returned inputs to a socket. The socket modifies these values and sends back to the servlet. Something of this nautre..

Comment: This 'Socket' would it be written in Java - and any specific reason why you want to implement a socket only or that is just a generic idea?

Comment: servlet 1: www.example.servlet1
servlet 2: www.example.servlet2
.servlet 1 has to send as a response a form to the browser. This form contains userName. When it sends it to the browser, the clients modifies this userName and by clicking the send button, the new value is sent back to servlet 1. Now, servlet1 sends this modified userName to servlet 2 who also modifies it and sends back to servlet 1. My question is: Is there a way I can establish a continuous connection between the two servlets and how will I know that servlet2 has finished modifying the file so that servlet1 can get it again?

Comment: it will be written in java and I have added more information concerning what I intend to achieve by doing this.

Comment: Ok. I get it. Well the above code with minor modification will work. I have provided it below `URL url = new URL("http://example.servlet2");
     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
     if(httpConn.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
     {
      InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
      
      //read the is
      
     }`  
The above call is a blocking one. Which means that when servlet1 will call servlet2, it will not complete till servlet2 complete successfully or throws an error. So if control enters if block it was processed.

Comment: to pass the data from servlet1 to servlet2 the easiest option is through request parameter i.e. http://example.servlet2?username=MYVALUE and the same can be accessed in servlet2 via `request.getParameter("username")`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51364/discussion-between-helpdesk-and-adityakeyal)

Answer (score 0):

You confuse servlets and sockets it looks like. Here is the difference:

- Sockets are used for a low-level communication between two points in network. By low-level I mean that you basically send whatever binary data you want over socket and receive some data back. In order to establish a connection there should be a `ServerSocket` waiting for connections and client socket which establishes connection with server socket.
- Servlet is J2EE abstraction. Servets are used in web application containers and those work on top of some protocol (in most cases HTTP). Servlets don't work with sockets, although web server uses sockets internally. Servlets work with `Request` and `Response` objects. Your servlet is responsible for processing user request and forming a response.