# FTP login with @

Tags: android, upload, ftp

I am building a basic android app that uploads a photo to my website with FTP.

The website's FTP is configured such that the server is
www.xxxxx.com:21
the user is
ftpup@www.xxxx.com
and pass is
ftpup123

When I run the following with these credentials I get an error saying that -1 is an invalid port, I assume because it expects the port to follow the .com and since .com exists twice due to the user it fails.

When I then run it with the user as simply "ftpup" it says that it cannot login PASS invalid

```
public static void upload( String ftpServer, String user, String password,
         String fileName, File source ) throws MalformedURLException,
         IOException
   {
      if (ftpServer != null && fileName != null && source != null)
      {
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );
         // check for authentication else assume its anonymous access.
         if (user != null && password != null)
         {
            sb.append( URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8") );
            sb.append( ':' );
            sb.append( password );
            sb.append( '@' );
         }
         sb.append( ftpServer );
         sb.append( '/' );
         sb.append( fileName );
         /*
          * type ==&gt; a=ASCII mode, i=image (binary) mode, d= file directory
          * listing
          */
         sb.append( ";type=i" );

         BufferedInputStream bis = null;
         BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
         try
         {
            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));
            int i;
            // read byte by byte until end of stream
            while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
               bos.write( i );
            }
         }
         finally
         {
            if (bis != null)
               try
               {
                  bis.close();
               }
               catch (IOException ioe)
               {
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
            if (bos != null)
               try
               {
                  bos.close();
               }
               catch (IOException ioe)
               {
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
         }
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println( "Input not available." );
      }
   }
```

Comment: In the variable 'ftpServer' I am guessing that you have it set to 'yourDomain.com:21'. Have you tried setting it to just "yourDomain.com". The port solution should be automatic when you specify the FTP protocol.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200106/urlconnection-ftp-list-files